# Best way to tally objects in an area with collision? (Unity3D - C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What would be the best way to tally objects that are tagged under a specific name? What am i doing wrong? My current goal is to use a box collider to identify and tally up specific objects in a room.  Any response to a solution or an alternative way of achieving this goal will be appreciated.

My attempt:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class roomColliders : MonoBehavior {

    public int numberOfTargets;

    void Start (){
        numberOfTargets = 0;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Target"){
            numberOfTargets += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, I tried assigning with Box Colliders and Rigidbody in a myriad of ways with the objects and I had no success.  I have three objects with a tag of "Target" assigned to them but in my inspector, the numberOfTargets tallies up only one object.  I have come under the conclusion, that maybe I need to use a statement such as this "foreach(ContactPoint contact  in col.contacts)".  I could be wrong, tell me if so.  If this is near the answer.  Is it anyway I can assign 'col.contacts.tag = "Target"'?  I get an error if I do so if I used it with 'foreach'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only you haven't do it intentionally, using **OnCollisionEnter** is wrong. You must use **OnTriggerEnter** instead. And do not forget to toggle on **Is Trigger** property on box collider attached to the object with **roomColliders** script.

And note that your script does not actually calculate number of objects currently intersected the trigger. It calculates number of times when objects of interest were start to intersect the trigger. But since the trigger may be moved to and fro, the same object of interest may intersect it more than once.